# Covariance / Stationary time series

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

Evaluate the mean and covariance function for each of the following processes. In each case, determine whether or not the process is stationary.

a) $Y_t$ = $\theta_0$ +t$e_t$

b) $W_t$ = $\nabla$$Y_t$ where $Y_t$ is given in part a).

c) $Y_t$=$e_t$*$e_{t-1}$

for part a)

E[$Y_t$]=E[$\theta_0$ +t$e_t$] = $\theta_0$+tE[$e_t$]=$\theta_0$ (due to 0 mean)

then Covariance = E[$Y_t$$Y_s$]-E[$Y_t$]E[$Y_s$]

where E[$Y_t$$Y_s$]=E[($\theta_0$ +t$e_t$)($\theta_0$ +s$e_s$)]=$\theta_0^2$+$\theta_0$sE[$e_s$]+$\theta_0$tE[$e_t$]+$ts^2$ E[$e_t$$e_s$] = $\theta_0^2$

This would mean that Covariance =  $\theta_0^2$ - $\theta_0$$\theta_0$=0??

Comment: You didn't write anything about the properties of $e_t$ which is crucial. In your formula for $E[Y_t]$ you need to make a correction: $E[Y_t]=E[θ_0 +te_t] = θ_0+tE[e_t]$.

Comment: Sorry, let $e_1$,$e_2$... be a sequence of independent, identically distributed random variables, each with mean of 0 and variance $\sigma_e^2$

Comment: Then $E[Y_t]=\theta_0$, among other things. Do you know the definition of stationarity?

Comment: You made the wrong edit -- the definition has to remain $Y_t = θ_0 +te_t$.

Comment: Stationarity seems to be that E[X], Var[X], and Cov[X] are the same regardless of t,s and k (k if there's a lag). From the looks of this you could choose an t, s or k and have the same answer, because those variables aren't included in the final answer. I'm assuming that means that a) is stationary?

Comment: As you showed, $cov(Y_t,Y_s)=0$ for $t\neq s$. But find the variance $V[Y_t]$. In the definition of covariance stationarity $E[Y_t]$ and $V[Y_t]$ do not depend on $t$ and $cov(Y_t,Y_s)$ can depend on $|t-s|$ (but not on $t$, $s$ individually).

Comment: Basically, your conclusion in a) should be that the process is NOT covariance stationary unless $\sigma^2_e=0$.